# BlackBerry: Button with Images for normal, focused and pressed state

Tags: blackberry, button, user-interface

I'd like to create an Image Button that has three states:

- Normal
- Focused
- Pressed (or "down" or "active" whatever you call it)

Normal and Focused is pretty straightforward. I used the well-known classes BaseButtonField and BitmapButtonField as a bases. My Problem is that

`protected boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time)`

is not called. My Button extends from `Field` and has `Field.FOCUSABLE | Field.EDITABLE` as styles. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with ["Tutorial: Creating a custom button"](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29251/Creating_a_custom_button_1676236_11.jsp) of the official RIM docs.

I think it is what your looking for

Answer (score 1):

The below code is a custom button field for bottom menu bar. This will be useful for your task.

```
public class PictureBackgroundButtonField extends BitmapField {

    MyTooltip _tooltip;
    Bitmap mNormal;
    Bitmap mFocused;
    Bitmap mActive;
    String text;
    int mWidth;
    int mHeight;
    int xpos1;

    public PictureBackgroundButtonField(String text,Bitmap normal, Bitmap focused, int xpos) 
    {
        super(normal,FOCUSABLE);
        mNormal = normal;
        mFocused = focused;
        mWidth = mNormal.getWidth();
        mHeight = mNormal.getHeight();
        this.text=text;
        setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
        setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        xpos1 = xpos;
    }

    public String getText()
    {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text)
    {
        this.text=text;
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        Bitmap bitmap = mNormal;

        if(isFocus())
        {
            bitmap = mFocused;
        }
        else
        {
            bitmap = mNormal;
        }

        graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap, 0, 0); 
    }

    protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) {
    }

    protected void onFocus(int direction) {

        //lbt.setText(text);
        invalidate();
        super.onFocus(direction);
        if ( _tooltip != null ) {
            _tooltip.removeToolTip();
            _tooltip = null;
        }

        // Display tooltip at 50,50 for 5 seconds
        _tooltip = MyTooltip.addToolTip(UiApplication.getUiApplication(), text, xpos1, 270, 1);
    }

    protected void onUnfocus() {
        //lbt.setText("");
        invalidate();
        super.onUnfocus();
        if ( _tooltip != null ) {
            // We have displayed a Tooltip - remove it
            _tooltip.removeToolTip();
            _tooltip = null;
        }
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return mWidth;
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return mHeight;
    }

    protected void layout(int width, int height) {
        setExtent(mWidth, mHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code won't do the 'active' or 'pressed' state. You're not using the mActive variable.

Answer (score 0):

When a field is in the 'active' or 'pressed' state its visual state is set to `Field.VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE`. If you check for this in your `paint()` method by calling `Field.getVisualState()` you'll be able to change how your button is displayed when it's pressed.